# How can I count the average separately for all rows

Tags: c

It's a basic program, but I need to find out how to calculate the average for each row separately. Should I use more counts or should I use another loop?

```
int main()
{
    int r;
    int Count=0;
    double sum=0;
    double Average=0;
    double c,value;
    for (r=1; r<11; r++)
    {
        for(c=1; c<5; c++)
        {
            value=(rand()%10000)/100.0;

            if (value>=67.0)
            {
                Count++;
                printf("%5.2f  ",value);
                sumTotal=sumRow/sumCol;
                sum += value;
            }
            else
            {
                 printf("       ");
            }   
        }

        Average=sum/Count;
        if(Average == 0){
            printf("|     ");
        }
        else{
            printf("| %6.2f ",Average);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon, and about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]) even sooner.  You need to set `Count` and `sum` (consistency of capitalization?) to zero at the start of each iteration of the outer loop.  You don't show the declarations of `sumTotal`, `sumRow`, or `sumCol`, which is distracting/disturbing.

Comment: sorry for capitalization, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make the counters in outer loop

```
int main()
{
    int r;

    double c,value;
    for (r=1; r<11; r++)
    {
        int Count=0;
        double sum=0;
        double Average=0;  
        for(c=1; c<5; c++)
        {

            value=(rand()%10000)/100.0;

            if (value>=67.0)
            {
                Count++;
                printf("%5.2f  ",value);
            //    sumTotal=sumRow/sumCol;
                sum += value;
            }
            else
            {
                 printf("       ");
            }   
        }

        Average=sum/Count;
        if(Average == 0){
            printf("|     ");
        }
        else{
            printf("| %6.2f ",Average);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I commented out broken code.